# Remove all the action cards of a link list of cards

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I have used a card object to work with for which I have created a linklist of playing card.

From the link list of cards I'm trying to remove all the action cards. But removing the node or action cards does nothing. It always prints out all the cards with out removing it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CreateDeck {

class Node{
    Card uno_card; 
    Node next; 

    public Node (Card uno_card) {
        this.uno_card = uno_card;
        this.next = null;
        }
    }

public static CreateDeck playing_deck = new CreateDeck(); 

public Node head = null; 
public Node tail = null; 

public static Card[] primary_deck = new Card[108];

public void addCard(Card uno_card) {

    Node newNode = new Node(uno_card);

    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode; 
        tail = newNode; 
    }
    else {
        tail.next = newNode; 
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

public static void printDeck(Card[] cards){
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        System.out.println(cards[i].get_unoCard());
    }
}

public void display() {
    Node current = head ; 

    if (current == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty.\n");
        return; 
    }
    System.out.println("Uno Deck ::\n");
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.uno_card.get_unoCard());
        current = current.next; 
    }
}

public static void init_deck(){
    int index = 0;
    for (int color = 1; color <= 4; color++){
        for (int rank = 0; rank <= 26; rank++){
            if (rank <= 24)
                primary_deck[index] = new Card(rank, color);
            else
                primary_deck[index] = new Card(rank, 0);
            index++;
        }
    }
}

public void remove_actionCard(){
    Card temp_card;
    for (int color = 1; color <= 4; color++){
        for (int rank = 19; rank <= 26; rank++){
            if (rank <= 24)
                temp_card = new Card(rank, color);
            else
                temp_card = new Card(rank, 0);

            Node current = head, temp = null;

            if(current != null && current.uno_card == temp_card){
                head = current.next;
                return;
            }

            while ( current != null && current.uno_card != temp_card){
                temp = current;
                current = current.next;
            }

            if (current == null) {
                return;
            }

            temp.next = current.next;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanf = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int deck_count;
    int choice;
    int ans;

    System.out.println("How many decks do you want to use?\n"); 
    deck_count = scanf.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How do you want to shuffle the decks?\n 1. Together\n 2. Indivisually");
    choice = scanf.nextInt();

    init_deck();

    if (choice == 2){
        for (int j = 0; j < deck_count; j++){
            Card[] temp_deck = primary_deck;
            shuffle.shuffle(temp_deck, 108);
            for (int k = 0; k < 108; k++){
                playing_deck.addCard(temp_deck[k]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (choice == 1){
        Card[] temp_deck = new Card[108*deck_count];
        int to_card = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < deck_count; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 108; k++){
                temp_deck[to_card] = primary_deck[k];
                to_card++;
            }
        }
        shuffle.shuffle(temp_deck, 108*deck_count );
        for (int x = 0; x < 108*deck_count; x++){
            playing_deck.addCard(temp_deck[x]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to remove action cards from the game?\n 1. NO\n 2. YES");
    ans = scanf.nextInt();

    if (ans == 2){
        playing_deck.remove_actionCard();
    }

    playing_deck.display();
}
}
```

Comment: Better title now and improved text. Please write correct sentences that make sense!

Comment: `current.uno_card == temp_card` - don't compare objects using `==` but use `equals()` instead (and `! xxx.equals(yyy)` instead of `!=`). Also, why are you creating _new_ card objects when you're trying to _remove_ cards?